# What arc/episode is this from where Shinpachi is apologizing with Okita and Kagura?

Tags: gintama

[image: Shinpachi is apologizing with Okita and Kagura]

I recently watched episode 252 of *Gintama* and in the "sorry montage" (around 15:06) the first scene was this clip with Shinpachi apologizing with Okita and Kagura.

Could anyone tell me which arc or episode this was from? I can't seem to remember and it's driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While reverse searching the image, somehow I found a single site with the exact scene (but Chinese subtitle) on [Baidu](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/1771710197959894940.html).

I can't read Chinese, but with the help of Google Translate, it seems all of them answering with episode 20*, "Watch Out For Conveyor Belts!"

*according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Gintama_episodes_(season_1)): *Gintama* (season 1), episode 20.